# Passing actions down the stack via props

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have been using Redux for a few weeks now and I am very happy with it and I am getting used to a Redux way. I am using it with React. Still plenty to learn as both things are new to me.

I have a one problem - maybe I am doing something wrong ... Let me show you:

I have a component structure that looks like this:

```
App  //root of the application aka smart component
  CampaignTable 
    CampaignHeaderRow 
      CampaignHeader 
    CampaignDataRow
      CampaignData
```

The App component is initialized as(only related code):

```
import * as DashboardActions from '../actions.js'

function select(state){
  return {
    campaigns: state.campaigns,  // array of campaign objects, has name, id, time created etc
    order: state.order // sort format "byWhichField" 
                       // will affect the way how campaigns are displayed
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return bindActionCreators(DashboardActions, dispatch) 
}

export default connect(select, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

App has now access to state and all actions as props.

The problem I see with it right now is:

I would like **CampaignHeader** to fire the action that will change the **state.order** state. Let say I will make `<th>Text</th>` inside **CampaignHeader** clickable. This will fire the action to change **state.order** which will in turn affect campaigns order on a next rerender.

So I have my action available inside **App** props. To pass it down to 
**CampaignHeader** I would have to:

- pass it down to **CampaignHeader** as props
- assign it to variable inside **CampaignHeader** and pass it down as props to **CampaignHeaderRow**
- assign it to variable inside **CampaignHeaderRow** and pass it down as props to **CampaignHeader**
- assign it to variable inside **CampaignHeader** and fire the action inside onClick event....

**This is a lot of boilerplate, assignments and bag passing! Just to get action fired.**

**All the components along the way are aware of this action.**

When I decided to implement this feature I have opened **CampaignHeader** component file. I have added the logic and called the action, I have added the action to action file. All I needed is to get a props set. **CampaignHeader** component doesn't hold a reference to its parent so I didn't know straight away where should this props be injected from(in this example is obvious but I hope you get a point).

**What if I will have even deeper component structure?**

**Is this approach correct?**

**Could I tackle this problem differently?**

*UPDATE:*

As @Errorpro suggested will it be ok to connect **single action** and **state.order** to **CampaignHeader**?

Worried about: **If I will do it once I will be doing it all the time.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a discussion in the issue-section of the Redux github repo about wether it's okay to use multiple connects or if everything should be passed down from the top through props, and in there Dan Abramov (the creator of Redux say's:

> [...]
>
> Nobody advocates a single connect.
>
> [...]
>
> The "single" only refers to small apps like the one we create in the
>   example. Please feel free to amend the docs to better clarify this. I
>   am now busy with other projects so please don't expect this issue to
>   get any movement unless somebody makes a PR. You can do it too.

The comment probably makes more sense in context though so check out the entire issue thread https://github.com/rackt/redux/issues/419#issuecomment-140782462

Answer (score 1):

If you use redux you should know about dumb and smart component. So we use this sctructure:

```
component
  index.js
  Component.js
  ComponentContainer.js
```

Dumb component just get props and render it. More interesting in smart component. Here it is:

```
export default compose(
  relay({
    fragments: {
      viewer: () => Relay.QL`
        fragment on Viewer {
           any data from relay
        }
      `,
    },
  }),
  connect(
    null,
    {
      onCreate: createUserAction,
    },
    (stateProps, actionProps, parentProps) => ({
      ...parentProps,
      onCreate={() => actionProps.onCreate('user')},
    })
  ),
)(Component);
```

So, parentProps and onCreate function will be in dumb component's props. There you can use this.props.onCreate and invoke it or pass it farther.

Comment: but that passing farther is my problem, I have to do it 4 times in my simple example. I get the idea on how the flow work just find it odd to have to do it this way

Comment: In react.js there is only 1 correct way to pass it further - props. And if you use redux-connect your way is ok. If you need to get this action in final distination you use smart component there and invoke your action there. In your case would be good create CampaignHeaderContainer and connect dispatch and action there. As in my example.

Comment: so you are suggesting to add another connect to **CampaignHeaderRow**?

Comment: Yes, why not? You can connect any component to redux. It's ok.

Comment: No no, you want to fire the action in CampaignHeader, am i right?

Comment: `export default compose(
  connect(
    null,
    {
      myAction: DashboardActions,
    },
    (stateProps, actionProps, parentProps) => ({
      ...parentProps,
      myAction: () => actionProps.myAction(),
    })
  ),
)(CampaignHeader);`

Comment: in dumb component `render() { return <button onClick={this.props.myAction}/>}'

Comment: OK I get it, I will think about it. Thank you mate!

Answer (score 1):

Passing the actions - like any other props - from parent to child to grandchild etc is the idiomatic React way. In my opinion your approach is correct; even if it feels wrong.

But there are a couple of alternatives.

There is a feature in React called context. Context permits the passing of fields from a higher order component to a lower order component whilst skipping the middlemen. However, it's an experimental feature so I would recommend avoiding it for now. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html

Additionally, there is a Redux specific way where you can make any lower order node of your choosing a "smart component" (in the Redux sense). That is, you wrap your class export in the connect function to plug it directly to the store, in the exact same way you do for the Root node.

Personally I tend to stick to the top-down way. There may be a fair bit of boilerplate involved but at least it means your application is easy to reason about.

Comment: so wouldn't you be tempted to connect **single action** and a small **very specific part** of the store to **CampaignHeader** as @Errorpro suggested?

Comment: My approach is usually to minimise my smart components. i.e. A single smart root component. Or, when using react-router, several smart route handlers. But do whatever you feel makes sense to do.

Comment: It is a javascript so it is a wild wild west... you can do whatever you like ;P I can make my store global and show the middle to the world.  I am more interested in getting general opinion on how the community would tackle this problem. Thank you mate!:)